# Devise custom after_update_path_for not being called(Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using devise and want to specify different redirect after updating a user based on a conditional statement. I did follow this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile and it is not calling my custom after_update_path_for method.

`routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations], :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }

as :user do
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'    
  put 'users/:id' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            
end
```

The reason I have the skip registrations is because I do not wish to have the new and create routes for the user. I am not sure if the issue is with the routes or something else.

Here is the `registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
    def after_update_path_for(resource)
      binding.pry
      if current_user.position == "owner" && current_user.sign_in_count == 1
        hub_landing_path
      end
    end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is really stumping me so if anyone has any ideas I would love to try them out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change

```
put 'users/:id' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
```

to use your custom `RegistrationsController` controller. So it'll be:

```
put 'users/:id' => 'registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with the route.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @NARKOZ does not work for me for Rails 4. I had to override the Devise Passwords controller like this:

```
# users/passwords_controller.rb
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
 protected
 def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  signed_in_root_path(resource)
 end
end
```

There is documentation on this method here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in